# Transform app.config entries only if a flag in app.debug.config is true

Tags: visual-studio, config, app-config, slowcheetah, xdt-transform

I would like to perform an `xdt:Transform` when in `Debug` configuration but only if the value of an entry in `app.debug.config` is a certain value, lets say `true` to keep it simple. For example:

**App.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings> 
    <add key="Value.First" value="foo" />
    <add key="Value.Second" value="foo" />
    <add key="Value.Third" value="foo" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**App.Debug.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <!--Convenient flag to indicate if transform should happen-->
    <add key="Perform.Transform.If.True" value="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />

    <!--Should only happen if the above is true-->
    <add key="Value.First" value="bar" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="Value.Second" value="bar" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
    <add key="Value.Third" value="bar" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I would like all of the `Value.*` entries in app.config to be transformed only if the key `Perform.Transform.If.True` is set to `true`.  If it is `false` nothing should happen. The reason being that sometimes during testing we would like to quickly turn things on and off which are controlled by the config files.

I have seen the options for `Locator` for things like Match, Conditional, XPath, etc. but none seem to allow for a ***condition from another entry***.  Can that be done with slowcheetah/xdt transforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found a round-about way using `XPath`:

```
 <add
    key="Value.First" 
    value="bar" 
    xdt:Transform="Replace"
    xdt:Locator="XPath(//appSettings/add[@key='Perform.Transform.If.True' and translate(@value, 'ERTU', 'ertu')='true']/../add[@key='Value.First'])" 
/>
```

If the flag is not `true` it will fail to resolve the path.  The `translate` makes it case-insensitive.

Failing to resolve (is `false`) leads to compile warnings which is annoying but since this is a debug tool we can live with that.